# running part of php file asynchronously

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous

I would like to run part of php code asynchronously. I want to run the insertnumber() function after 60seconds but without delaying the whole code.

```
 echo json_encode($returnArray);
 if ($timeout=="1")
{
  sleep(60);
  $connection->insertnumber($finalnumber,"Loser");
}
```

This method delay the whole code by 60 secs. I want that part of the code to run in the background without affecting the original code and then executing the insernumber() function after 60 secs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP how to have code continue without waiting for results of include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925550/php-how-to-have-code-continue-without-waiting-for-results-of-include)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP by default runs synchronously. Have a look at the following question which has a few different methods on how to run PHP asynchronously, using either PHP OOP Threads or some built it PHP Process methods:

[How can one use multi threading in PHP applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855/how-can-one-use-multi-threading-in-php-applications)

Additionally, if you are building something that will be running in the browser, have a look at using Javascript asynchronous functions to achieve what you desire:

[What is a simple example of an asynchronous javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806695/what-is-a-simple-example-of-an-asynchronous-javascript-function)